# Need Some Guidance on Passing Value from the Dialog box to textarea

Tags: javascript

I am using the dialog box to add some value from the dialog box to the textarea, but i am sure something is wrong, where the following is not working. It is not even showing me the alert

```
function makecode(formName,editor) {
    $('#codeEditor').dialog({ 
        height: 250, 
        width: 400, 
        modal: true, 
        resizable: false, 
        title: "Create Code for the FAQ Question", 
        show: {effect: "blind",duration: 1000}, 
        hide: {effect: "explode",duration: 1000}, 
        beforeclose: function() {
        $("#answer").val($.this.attr('id').text());
        alert(this.attr('id').text());
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }); 
    document.forms[formName].elements[editor].focus();
}

<div id="codeEditor" style="display:none;height:200px;">
<div align="left" class="showborders" contenteditable="true" id="sendDataBack"></div>
<br />
<div align="left">The above block is editable, write any code inside it and it will be displayed inside the FAQ's Answers</div> 
</div>

<input type="button" name="bCode" value=" Code " onClick="makecode('formFaqs','answer');" alt="Use this button to insert Code." title="Use this button to insert Code.">
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).attr('id').text()`?

Comment: I tried that code, but it is not working too, even alert is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved if anyone comes here looking for an answer: Here is what i  did

```
function makecode(formName,editor) {
    $('#codeEditor').dialog({ 
        height: 250, 
        width: 400, 
        modal: true, 
        resizable: false, 
        title: "Create Code for the FAQ Question", 
        show: {effect: "blind",duration: 1000}, 
        hide: {effect: "explode",duration: 1000}, 
        close: function() {
        var addData = $("#sendDataBack").text();
        var textbox = $("#answer");
        textbox.val(textbox.val() + '<div class="code">' + addData + '</div>');
        $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }); 
    document.forms[formName].elements[editor].focus();
}
```

If anyone has better way of doing it, please update the answer